# Sed/Awk to search and replace/insert text in files

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I am trying to update or insert few comments like Copyright headers in to all my source files in a directory (Linux). My files are inconsistent, so that a few of them already have headers while others do not have them at all. I tried with `sed` to look at the first few lines and replace. Replace I mean change the files which are already having Copyright header with latest one.

```
sed -e '1,10 s/Copyright/*Copyright*/g' file
```

But, this will not insert if it did not find the pattern. How can I achieve this?

Example I provided in comments or what I am trying to actually replace/insert is a multiline typical copyright header as follows

```
/*
* Copyright 1234 XXXNAME, XYZPlace 
*  text text text text ...........
* blah blah blah */
```

It may contain some special characters also.

Comment: Show us example data and you will get more accurate answers.

Comment: `sed -e '1,10 s/Copyright/*Copyright*/g' file || sed insert text...`

Comment: @Anders Why would that work? Won't `sed` return 0 in any case, or am I missing something?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Ah you're right, it does return zero in any case.

Comment: here is example data     /******************************************************************** sometext year  *  blah *  blah,...............................                                */                                                                   Now I am trying to see if sometext is existing, if its there then replace/update sometext year with sometext year - current year if not insert sometext currentyear

Comment: Please include all the variations of sample data you want supported in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

- Find files without a Copyright notice in the first 10 lines, and
- Add a Copyright notice to those files.

In addition, you want to:

- Find files WITH a Copyright notice in the first 10 lines, and
- Update their notice to your standard text.

It seems to me that these two tasks could be boiled down to a single set:

- Remove any existing Copyright notice in the first 10 lines, then
- Insert a new Copyright notice into the file.

If we can safely assume that a shortened version of the sampletext you put in a comment on your question is valid, and should be inserted at, for example, line 2 of each file, then the following should achieve the very first set of requirements if you're using GNU sed:

```
find . -type f -not -exec grep -q Copyright {} \; -exec sed -i'' '2i/* Copyright */' {} \;
```

If you're *not* running GNU sed (i.e. you're in FreeBSD or OSX or Solaris, etc), let us know, because the sed script will be different.

**How does this work**?

The `find` command is getting the following options:

- `-type f` tells it to look only at files (not directories or devices).
- `-not` inverts the following option.
- `-exec grep -q Copyright {} \;` limits the search to anything with Copyright in it (modified by `-not`)
- `-exec sed -i'' '2i/* Copyright */' {} \;` inserts your copyright notice.

This solution may run into difficulty if you want your copyright notice to include special characters that would be interpreted by the sed script.  But it answers your question.  :)

If instead, we want to handle the revised requirements, i.e. remove existing copyright notices first, then we can do this with two one-liners:

First, we remove existing copyright notices.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'head {} | grep -q Copyright' \; -exec sed -ne '10,$ta;/Copyright/d;:a;p' {} \;
```

This may be a little redundant, unless you want to traverse subdirectories recursively, which `find` does by default.  The sed script does nothing to files that have no Copyright info in the first 10 lines, so the following should also work instead, if all your files are in one directory:

```
for file in *;do sed -ne '10,$ta;/Copyright/d;:a;p' "$file"; done
```

Next, we add new ones back in.

```
for file in *;do sed -i'' '2i/* Copyright */' "$file"; done
```

Or, if you want to do this recursively through subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i'' '2i/* Copyright */' {} \;
```

**FINAL UPDATE**:

I can't spend more time on this one after this.

```
find . -type f \
  -exec sh -c 'head {} | grep -q Copyright' \; \
  -exec sed -ne '1h;1!H;${;g;s:/\*.*Copyright.*\*/:/* Copyright 1998-2012 */' {} \;
```

**What**?

The first `-exec` searches for the word "Copyright" in the first 10 lines of the file.  Just like the first example I posted, above.  If grep finds anything, this condition returns true.

The second `-exec` does the substitution.  It reads the entire file into sed's hold buffer.  Then when it gets to the end of the file, it (`g`) considers the hold buffer, and (`s`) does a multi-line substitution.

Note that this may very well require some tuning, and it may not work at all if you have comments elsewhere in the file.  I don't recall whether GNU sed supports non-greedy stars.  You can research that yourself.

Here's my test:

```
$ printf 'one\n/* Copyright blah blah\n *\n */\ntwo\n' | sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s:/\*.*Copyright.*\*/:/* Copyright 1998-2012 */:g;p;}'
one
/* Copyright 1998-2012 */
two
```

This *doesn't* maintain your existing Copyright information, but at least it addresses the multi-line issue.

Comment: I am using GNU sed only, I understand what you are doing here. You are filtering all files which do not have have Copyright and then inserting Copyright at second line, this is kind of solves my problem but not completely. As I mention I wanted to update the files which already have Copyright also, and these are inconsistent. few files may have at line 2 and few at line one or somewhere else in first 10 lines. Lets say Sometext 1998 in a file that I am planning to update Sometext 1998 - 2012.

Comment: So ... you also want to REMOVE existing lines that contain the copyright notice / sampletext?  And you want to do all this *only* if that text appears within the first 10 lines of the file?  These criteria aren't mentioned in your question.  Perhaps you could [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11563620/edit) and add them?

Comment: What about doing this in two stages?  I don't think it's possible to do a one-liner this way that will update OR insert depending on your criteria, but you could easily do a one-liner that REMOVES existing lines, followed by this one to INSERT them.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti, I will edit the question. Yeah you are correct, these details are more likely to be in first 10 lines and yes I want to replace the existing text with latest one (like latest year for obsolete ones). I guess I can fist filter the files which do not have Copyright and insert text in them later I can search/replace on whole files. I feel like its double time work so looking for optimal ways.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if I remove the old header, I will end up loosing from which date it's existing. Since its kind of copyright information, I am planning to update old headers as span of creation date - current date.

Comment: Sigh.  This new information that the text to replace is multi-line eliminates my entire answer.  Along with all the other answers that have been provided so far.  :-(

Comment: Well, thats my overall objective. I can work around to get done that if I achieve this ( for at leat single line or word).

Comment: Thanks ton, it will definitely help me to work around fix my objectives.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the command below won't work if you have file names with spaces, see the first comment.

It can for sure be done with `sed` only, but the first thing that came to my mind is to do the substitution on files where the line is present and then add the header to the rest of the files using something like

```
for f in $(grep -lv 'Copyright' *); do sed -i '1i *Copyright*' $f; done
```

That will work for all files in the current folder, use the `-r` option to `grep` if you need recursion.

P.S. I suggest removing the `-i` `sed` option for testing and adding it only when you're sure the command works right.

Comment: This notation is one of the common [Bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  You definitely shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

To insert the single line containing the text `copyright` at line 1 of a file only if it isn't already there, you could do:

```
sed '1{ /copyright/!i\
copyright
}' input-file
```

To insert multiple lines:

```
sed '1{ /copyright/!i\
copyright\
second line
}' input-file
```

It's tempting to use `r` to read the copyright from a file, but I cannot figure out how to insert it before line 1 rather than after line 1.  eg:

```
sed '1{ /copyright/! { x; r copyright-file
G}}' input-file
```

Seems like it ought to do the trick, but the text from the copyright-file winds up starting at line 2.

Comment: This one looks at only first line right?, but I wanted to look in at least 1 to 10 lines and replace first occurrence or insert at top of the file.

Comment: Preprocess the file list: make one list of files that do not contain the copyright, and a second list of those that do.

Comment: The `r` command always appends to the current line on output. It doesn't read into the pattern space, so unfortunately the lines of the file can't be manipulated.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis.  For reference: `the contents of the file specified for the r command, shall be written to standard output just before the next attempt to fetch a line of input when executing the N or n commands, or when reaching the end of the script... The contents of the file specified for the r command shall be as of the time the output is written, not the time the r command is applied.`