# Paste header line in multiple tsv (tab separated) files

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have multiple .tsv files named as `choochoo1.tsv`, `choochoo2.tsv`, ... `choochoo(nth).tsv` files. I also have a `main.tsv` file. I want to extract the header line in `main.tsv` and paste over all `choochoo(nth).tsv` files. Please note that there are other `.tsv` files in the directory that I don't want to change or paste header, so I can't do `*.tsv` and select all the `.tsv` files (so need to select `choochoo` string for wanted files). This is what I have tried using bash script, but could not make it work. Please suggest the right way to do it.

```
for x in *choochoo; do
    head -n1 main.tsv > $x
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding header into multiple text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196993/adding-header-into-multiple-text-files)

Comment: @muru I saw that post, but that did not help !

Comment: @MAPK: Why didn't it help?  It deals with almost exactly the situation you face.  The only marginal difference (emphasis on 'marginal') is that you need to collect the line to be inserted from the first line of another file; that isn't enough of a difference to warrant claiming "it does not help".  You are allowed to think for yourself.  (It's also a good idea to explain why something that should help doesn't help.)

Comment: Script which you tried `not make it work` - what is it mean? Is your problem that you **failed to iterate over only needed files** (so having this problem resolved, you can paste header line *by yourself*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the file glob, as well as the redirect:

- the file glob will catch things like `AAchoochoo` but not `choochoo1.tsv` and not even `AAchoochoo.tsv`
- the redirect will overwrite the existing files instead of adding to them. The redirect command for adding to a file is `>>`, but that will append text to the end and you want to prepend text in the beginning.

The problem with prepending text to an existing file, is that you have to open the file for both reading and writing and then stream both prepended text and original text, in order - and that is usually where people fail because the shell can't open files like that (there is a slightly more complex way of doing this directly, by opening the file for both reading and writing, but I'm not going to address that further).

You might want to use a temporary file, something like this:

```
for x in choochoo[0-9]*.tsv; do
  mv "$x"{,.orig}
  (head -n1 main.tsv; cat "$x.orig") > $x
  rm "$x.orig"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how do you include files with alpha numeric values at the end? Is it like doing something like this :` for x in chochoo[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]*.tsv`?

Comment: The * in the glob means "everything else", and not " repeat last clause" as in a regular expression, so `choochoo[0-9]*.tsv` can match `choochoo2.tsv` as well as `choochoo2nd.tsv`. Read up on the difference between globs and regexps.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is what if it is choochooX.tsv

Comment: Well, tailor your glob to what you need - if you need to find both suffixes, then maybe just `*` would do. Often it's easier to just say "catch everything" and then think about how to fix the glob to not catch what you don't want, instead of planning who to catch only exactly what you need.