# The best way in Unix to add a header to multiple files in a directory?

Tags: unix, sed

Before anyone else checks, I am confident this is **not** a duplicate of the existing question of how to add a header in Unix to multiple files (the question is here: [Adding header into multiple text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196993/adding-header-into-multiple-text-files)). This is more about optimisation of a solution I am currently using for this current issue.

I have numerous directories in which I have over 20000 files and for each file I want to add the same header.

What I have been doing is:

```
sed -i '1ichr\tpos\tref\talt\treffrq\tinfo\trs\tpval\teffalt\tgene' *.txt
```

Now, this does work exactly as I want it to, but there have been a couple of issues.

First is that this seems to be an extremely slow method of doing this and it can take a pretty long time to get through all 20K+ files.

Second, and more frustratingly, occasionally my connection to the server I am using has timed out during this long process meaning that the command won't finish running, so I end up with half the files having the header and half not. And if I started from the top again this would mean a number of the files would have the header twice so I actually have to go through a process of creating them again so I can add the header all at once.

So, what I am wondering is if there is a better/quicker solution to this problem. The question I linked above seems like it would actually be slower (given that it seems like there is more the command line needs to do at each file as it is going through a loop) and so doesn't seem like it would fix this.

Comment: To prevent the connection timeout being an issue, run the command in `tmux`.

Comment: And to prevent the issue of corrupted data (only a portion of the files are processed), do *not* use `sed -i`.  It is truly an abomination.  Create new files with the header.  Since you have a lot of files, create them in a new directory.  When all the new files are created, rename the directories.

Comment: What is ```tmux``` and what does it do, is it something one can use with sed? Also, what exactly is the issue with ```sed -i```? I feel like these comments would be best as an answer in their own right because I don't fully understand them.

Comment: Also, for the final aspect there, do you mean create the same number of files with just the header and then somehow paste over the actual contents of the files from the ones without the header to the ones with the header?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-tmux-8d784c404340

Comment: `sed -i` is evil because you cannot know what state your files are in if it is interrupted.  When you are manipulating files, you don't want to accidentally lose data, but it's difficult to know how `sed -i` will behave if it is interrupted (power failure, network connection, signal, hardware failure, etc.) Better to leave the input untouched and write a new file. For your last question; yes, just use `sed` without `-i` and write the output to a file with the same name in a different directory.  When you're done, rename the directories.

Comment: Ahh, so ```tmux``` is like ```screen```? That's useful to know, thanks.

Comment: `tmux` is not like `screen`!  It is *much* better! :)

Comment: And that sounds exactly like the issues I'm having with ```sed -i```, in that when it's crashed I basically have to start from the top because I have no idea how far it got. I'm pretty inexperienced with ```sed``` though, so I'm not sure how I would make these output files and copy the contents over like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `-i`.  It confuses things when you get interrupted.  Instead, use

```
mkdir -p ../output-dir
for file in *.txt; do 
  sed '1ichr\tpos\tref\talt\treffrq\tinfo\trs\tpval\teffalt\tgene' "$file" > ../output-dir/"$file"
done
```

When you're done, you can rename the directories if you wish.  This doesn't address the connection issue (ThoriumBR's suggestion of `nohup` is good for that), but when it happens you can recover state more easily.

Answer (score 0):

First, adding a header **is slow**. You have to move the entire file contents to add something at the start. Adding a trailer would be very fast.

Second, use [nohup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

Using `nohup sed -i '1ichr\tpos\tref\talt\treffrq\tinfo\trs\tpval\teffalt\tgene' *.txt` will keep the command running on the background even if the server times you out.

Comment: I can give it a shot using nohup! Thanks. I also think it's necessary for me to add a header simply for convention if nothing else (so you can see what the data is in each file) and also because eventually these will be input into R which will need to read them from the header.